# How do I transfer podcasts to an iPod shuffle (2nd gen) in macOS Catalina?

Tags: podcasts, catalina, ipod-shuffle

When I plug in an iPod shuffle (2nd generation), it appears in the sidebar under Devices in the new Music app, but not in the new Podcasts app. The iPod also appears as a location in Finder, but the "Podcasts" tab does not appear. How do I transfer Podcasts to the iPod?

[image: Finder Screenshot]

Comment: My answer doesn't address iPod shuffle and the link text [here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT210611) at the bottom of the page being: *if you see an error when you try to sync your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch.* gives the impression that touch models work with Finder for sync. Please add answers for Shuffle model. [Identify your iPod model](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204217)

Comment: It's a 2nd generation shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

My ipod shuffle would not show up in the finder when I plugged it in. Here's a workaround that worked for me:

1. Open Music App
2. Click on your iPod shuffle in the sidebar
3. You should see a Sync Settings button in the upper right
4. That will open the finder window where you can sync podcasts

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I end up back at the finder window in the image above, with no sync tab for podcasts.